# How to authenticate GitHub with HTTParty to scrape a page?

Tags: ruby, authentication, github, httparty

I'm trying to scrape this page:

```
https://github.com/search?p=1&q=https%3A%2F%2Fsonarcloud.io%2Fdashboard&type=Code
```

and I need to authenticate with my email and password.

I have tried to do that:

```
auth = {:usarname => "username", :password => "password"}

a = HTTParty.get(url, :basic_auth)
```

but this didn't authenticate me as expected.

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

I want retrive that information, and isn't available on the Github API:

[image]

Comment: What is "that information"? You're looking for the specific files and lines that match your search?

Answer (score 0):

Don't scrape GitHub. Scraping is fragile, and very awkward with sites that make heavy use of JavaScript.

Use [its API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) instead:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsonarcloud.io%2Fdashboard
```

To search across all repositories you'll still need to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), though. You need to pass your `auth` hash into `HTTParty.get()`:

```
auth = {:username => "username", :password => "password"}

a = HTTParty.get(url, :basic_auth => auth)
#                                 ^  Here
```

More idiomatically, this might look like

```
auth = {username: "username", password: "password"}

a = HTTParty.get(url, basic_auth: auth)
```

You also have a typo—`usarname` instead of `username`—which I've fixed in my version.

**Edit:** If you want to retrieve the specific matched text, file, and lines you still don't have to scrape their HTML. Instead, you can [set your `Accept` header to `application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json`](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#text-match-metadata):

```
url = "https://api.github.com/search/code"
query = {q: "https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard"}
auth = {username: "username", password: "password"}
headers = {"Accept" => "application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json"}

a = HTTParty.get(url, query: query, basic_auth: auth, headers: headers)
```

The response should now give a `text_matches` key containing hashes with `fragment`s showing the matched text as well as `object_type`s (e.g. `"FileContent"`), `object_url`s, and `indices`.

This is also mentioned in the [search code](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) link I already provided:

> When searching for code, you can get text match metadata for the file **content** and file **path** fields when you pass the `text-match` media type. For more details about how to receive highlighted search results, see [Text match metadata](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#text-match-metadata).

Comment: The typo was when I was writing here. I understand that scrape can be messy, but is the only way to retrive the informations that i need. Github API, dont return the content informations, just links.

Comment: I don't know what that edit is talking about, but this answer still applies. Even if you decide to scrape (again, avoid this if at all possible; it probably is) you need to pass your `auth` hash into the `HTTParty.get()` call.

Comment: I did just like you told and still don't work. The Scrape returns a sign in page.

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas, you _really_ should be using the API. I think I understand what you were saying in your edit. Please see if my new answer works. Make sure to use the API URL, not the regular search URL.

Comment: API dont work for what I'm trying to do. This link https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ shows the return of Github API, and the content that I'm trying to get is encoded.

Comment: And no, still not authenticating.

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas, then _please **clearly explain** what you want to do_. Your question is _unclear_. Please respond to my question above about what "that information" is, and how it isn't included in the API response. See [ask].

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas, also, that link you provide is for a completely different API endpoint than the one I'm suggesting. Why are you talking about the repository contents API? There's a search API that I recommended in my original answer four days ago.